# How to hide QButton label/text on small device?

Tags: quasar

I would like to have the button shows icon only on small device; and shows text when the clientWidth is big enough. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.You can dynamically bind icon and label bases on the platform.

```
 <q-btn square color="primary" text-color="white" :icon="$q.platform.is.mobile?'home':''" :label="$q.platform.is.mobile?'':'Home'">
 </q-btn>
```